# How to disabled Drupal builtin "poormanscron" cron when using Ultimate cron?

Tags: 7, cron

I want to disabled Drupal 7 builtin "poormanscron" to then put it into a crontab task as it should, but when using Ultimate cron module i do not see an option to disabled Drupal 7 builtin "poormanscron"

Do i have to uninstall ultimate cron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to uninstall any module. The setting you are looking for is on admin/config/system/cron/settings/poorman.

> [image: screenshot]

Change *Launcher* to *-- Disabled --* from the default *Serial*, and Poormanscron should not run anymore.

If you disable or uninstall the *Ultimate cron* module, Drupal shows the equivalent settings in admin/config/system/cron, at the bottom of the page.

> [image: screenshot]

In this case, change *Run cron every* to *Never*.

Comment: Yes but Ultimate Cron module overwrite that system path

Comment: I think i got it, under admin/config/system/cron/settings/poorman there is an option which says "Select the launcher to use for handling poormans cron." and i can desabled so i guessing it is that. The select Defaults to "Serial"

Comment: Looks like it is [https://www.drupal.org/node/2473575](https://www.drupal.org/node/2473575)

Comment: I misread the module name, and I thought you were referring to Poormanscron which is part of Drupal 7. I will update my answer.